# Oracle multi table SQL query

Tags: oracle

I have four tables. The Tables are given below.

inv_profile:

```
  accnt_no       ac_name1
    23            Prasun Kanti
    45            Babu
```

psdr_cds:(Use for Buy)

```
accnt_no     no_shares          trans_dt         comp_cd
 23              40             1-jan-2006         101
 45              70             11-dec-2011        101
 23              20             1-nov-2011         101
```

swr_cds(Use for Sale)

```
accnt_no      no_shares            trans_dt       comp_cd
   23              20              1-jan-2007       101
   45              20              12-dec-2011      101
   23              30              15-nov-2011      101
```

comp

```
   comp_cd       comp_nm
      101         AB BANK
```

Now i need a sql query that return the following result:

```
  Accnt_no     Name             Total Buy     Total Sale      Balance

     23        Prasun Kanti     60           50                10
     45        Babu             70           20                50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    i.acct_no AS "Accnt_no",
    i.ac_name1 AS "Name",
    SUM(p.no_shares) AS "Total Buy",
    SUM(s.no_shares) AS "Total Sale",
    SUM(p.no_shares) - SUM(s.no_shares) AS "Balance"
FROM inv_profile i
INNER JOIN psdr_cds p ON i.accnt_no = p.accnt_no
INNER JOIN swr_cds s ON i.accnt_no = s.accnt_no
GROUP BY i.acct_no, i.ac_name1
```

Comment: Dear sir,Thanks for your reply.If the tables contains more data then the result contains invalid data. In fact i want to search the result against comp_cd,trans_dt condition. Can you please verify this.

Comment: @prasun you didn't mention that in your question, but you could easily add another `JOIN` to the `comp` table and filter the data using a `WHERE` clause. I suggest you look at an introductory SQL tutorial such as http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp to help you.

Comment: Dear sir,can you kindly give you mail id then i can send the 4 tables data and you can easily understand what the problem is. I run your query it didn't show the valid total buy,total sale also Balance.Suppose psdr_cds contains 128 records and swr_cds contains 123 records then your query show only 123 rows based on swr_cds.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as 
( select ip.accnt_no, ip.ac_name1, ps.no_shares buy, sw..no_shares sale 
    from inv_profile ip, psdr_cds ps, swr_cds sw
   where ip.accnt_no = ps.accnt_no )
select t.accnt_no Accnt_no, 
       t.ac_name1 Name,
       sum(t.buy) Total_buy,
       sum(t.sale) Total_sale
       (sum(t.buy)-sum(t.sale)) Balance
  from t
 group by t.accnt_no, t.ac_name1
```

Will do. But there are many other ways, eg. `over partition by` etc.

HTH

Comment: Dear sir, This query shown this report-User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.

Comment: Then you had interrupted the query and/or lost your database connection.